# Reading character Array instead of String Array from flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a following table in `postgresql`.

```
class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Test'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    genres = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String(120)))
```

To save `genres` into the Test Table, I read values from the UI and store it in the DB through the following code,

```
genres = request.form.getlist('genres')
test = Test(name=name, genres=genres)
    db.session.add(test)
    db.session.commit()
```

and while reading it from the DB, I do,

```
test = Test.query.get(test_id)
data = test.serialize()
print(f'Data => {data}')
```

The **problem** I am running into is When I read `genres` from Test table it is returned as an array of characters,

```
'genres': ['{', 'A', 'l', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'v', 'e', ',', 'B', 'l', 'u', 'e', 's', ',', 'C', 'l', 'a', 's', 's', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l', '}']
```

rather than the way they were created/stored & saved into the table, which is an array of Strings,

```
genres = ['Alternative', 'Blues', 'Classical']
```

**Edit**: Even if I write the result before `Serialization` happens I still see this issue. Here is resulting `genres` upon running the `test.query.get('id'),

```
genres: ['{', 'A', 'l', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'v', 'e', ',', 'B', 'l', 'u', 'e', 's', ',', 'C', 'l', 'a', 's', 's', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l', '}']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Ran into this issue when I changed the column from `db.String()` to `db.ARRAY(db.String())` without migrating the database. The flask-migrate tool didn't detect any changes so I created the tables from scratch and used this line in the alembic script to create the column: `sa.Column('name', sa.ARRAY(sa.String()), nullable=True)`.

Comment: Recently I have to manage this kind of errors, for some reason I replicate
this issue after create a database where the name was set on **camelCase**
instead of **snake_case**. So if it is your case, dumo the table, drop it and
then create the new one, using snake_case `__tablename__ = "table_name"`

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue and unable to find the root cause. The strange thing is that the behavior is not consistent. One of the tables will convert to JSON correctly while some others do not.

My solution was to write a function that fixes the broken format.

```
def fix_json_array(obj, attr):
    arr = getattr(obj, attr)
    if isinstance(arr, list) and len(arr) > 1 and arr[0] == '{':
        arr = arr[1:-1]
        arr = ''.join(arr).split(",")
        setattr(obj,attr, arr)
```

Then I simply put this after I query the table.

```
record = myTable.query.get(row_id)
fix_json_array(record, "genres")
```